# Drupal 8 - Accessing a referenced entity through $fields (implementing validation on node creation)

Tags: validation, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, entityreference

Within a custom module, I'm working on validating a field based on an entry from another field. The validation works when the hash is hard coded (i.e. `// $bookhash = 1;`). However, I cannot seem to figure out how to access hash of the referenced book.

What's the proper way of accessing that data from book referenced within book_signatures?

```
use  \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter().
 */
function custom_validation_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($bundle === 'book_signatures') {


    if (isset($fields['field_confirm_book_hash'])) {

      $book = $fields['field_book']; // book is a referenced entity within book_signatures. 
      $bookhash = $book->field_hash_check; // need to set this equal to the hash in the book entity.
      // $bookhash = 1; works with static hash. need specific books hash
      $fields['field_confirm_book_hash']->addConstraint('BookHash', ['hash' => $bookhash]);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: output from devel on the field [$fields['field_book']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwadb.png). It's id outputs "node.book_signatures.field_book"

Answer (score 0):

Taking a slightly different approach exposed both fields more elegantly.

```
  /**

    * Implements hook_entity_type_build().

    */

  function custom_validation_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {

    // Add our custom validation to the order number.
    $entity_types['node']->addConstraint('BookHash');

  }
```